# The type initializer exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, exception, projects-and-solutions

I would like to make a order in the of solution.

It looks like this:

[image]

When I put DLL files into the OpenCV_DLL folder , like this:

[image]

I get this exceptions:

**{"The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."}**

Any idea why do i get those exceptions and how can i fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Open your dll with dependency walker, I think you should put some other dlls in your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are often wrapped. Unwrap the exceptions to get more detail about the problem:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    while(ex!=null) {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

You'll find the real problem underneath.

In this case, the problem is that the dlls will be deploying to the wrong location - into a sub-folder instead of next to the running assembly. You *could* try adding a probing-path to OpenCV_dll but frankly I'd just move them back to the root level. For info on adding a probing-path, see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx